# Accessing ArcGIS 9.3 geodatabase from 9.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, esri-geodatabase

If I'm using ArcGIS 9.2 is it possible to access a feature class from a geodatabase that was created by ArcGIS 9.3?

If not, are there any other ways to access the data?

Comment: What type of geodatabase are you using? Personal (MS Access), File, or ArcSDE?  That makes a huge difference because personal and file gdb are not "forward" compatible.

Answer (score 6):

[Based on the documention](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/geodatabases/client_1499998815.htm#webprint) it looks as if you can use 9.3 generated geodatabases, but only after [upgrading to SP5](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=59&MetaID=1377).

Comment: im sory ,,, so , how can i get this pack n how to install it?

Comment: There you go: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=listPatches&PID=43&FilterPV_4=352&FilterType_2=5&maxVersion=12&maxCategory=2&FilterVersion=+go+

Comment: my second link included download links, but Guillaume's is better: it also includes links to SP6.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very comprehensive table summarizing cross version connections at: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00290000003z000000.htm
Note that, if you need to connect to an SDE geodatabase, as opposed to personal or file geodatabase, you will need a specific client to install along your ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 SP5 or SP6. I think you can find the client on the ArcGIS Desktop installation DVD, and apply the relevant SP.